# SlickGrid V2 column Resize triggers Sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert, slickgrid

This may be an artifact but it is quite reproducable (IE only) in the couple Grids I've built since the switch to SlickGrid V2 (never saw this in previous version).  When a user Resizes a column, the Resort method also fires which, of course, resorts the column.
I've also done this (which has no effect):

```
grid.onColumnsResized.subscribe(function(e, args) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.stopPropagation();
    // alert('resized');
    return false;
});
```

But, when I include the alert... everything works as it should (no resort).  So... I'm thinking it's a timing issue.  I set up a false, 2 sec timer (does nothing but times) and that has no effect either (still resorts).
Can someone explain what's going on and why `alert` seems to allow everything to work properly.  It also doesn't matter whether I use the local Resort or the default SlickGrid Resort method.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of IE are you finding this problem in? SlickGrid explicitly doesn't support IE6. https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki

Comment: Thought I mentioned it, but I guess not... IE8 and maybe others but that's all I have.

Comment: Sorry for the super-late answer. I figured someone else would have gotten to it by now. :))

Answer (score 1):

Basically the problem is that IE is triggering a click event on the column when you resize. If there is a column header underneath your cursor when you mouseup, that column will be resorted.

As for why the alert box helps, browser events are fired in a particular order. In IE, dragend (which triggers onColumnsResized) is fired before click (which triggers a resort). Because they're not of the same type, stopping propagation won't do anything, but it's possible that popping up an alert box prevents the ghost click from being registered on the column header.

This is something that should be worked around in the SlickGrid library, not the code that uses it.